# Run Android Emulator Flutter app failed but iOS Simulator success

Tags: flutter, dart

Today,When I run Flutter app using Android Emulator in AndroidStudio,it give me a error but using iOS Simulator is successful, like this below:

BUILD FAILED in 1m 44s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1598)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
... 16 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

////////
any suggestions please!!!

Comment: Looks like your java isn't fine on your mac so you need to get it fixed first

Comment: it seem to be a little difficult for a native iOS developer, how to fix java problem???glad to your reply.

Comment: Remove the old java files completely and install fresh jdk8 or java sdk 16/17. I'll prefer jdk8. Make sure environment variable path is added in your mac and provide the java path to android studio if you are using it for flutter

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this

```
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This can be solved by adding environment variable for `jdk`. Or delete the .gradle folder under `C:\users'Your username'\`

Comment: This are some link that i refered, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59737

Comment: that delete gradle folder is does not work